# How to add security policy to API Gateway in CDK application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am trying to add a [TLS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.SecurityPolicy.html) to my API Gateway in my CDK app. But I am not sure where to add it to my API Gateway instance:

```
const api = new apiGateway.RestApi(this, "my-api", {..})
..
```

When I deploy this to AWS, I do see endpoints as

```
https://someid123.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod
```

I am guessing this already has TLS enabled (with `https`)? if so, how do I view the actual security policy used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST Api supports TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.0 and When we add a custom domain, we can choose to pass Security policy. We can't choose for default endpoint provided by AWS.

`securityPolicy: apigw.SecurityPolicy.TLS_1_2` to `domainName.securityPolicy`

```
const restapi = new apigw.RestApi(this, 'my-rest-api', {
    description: `test`,
    restApiName: `test-api`,
    endpointTypes: [apigw.EndpointType.REGIONAL],
    domainName: {
        securityPolicy: apigw.SecurityPolicy.TLS_1_2,
        domainName: `test-api.mydomain.com`,
        certificate: acm.Certificate.fromCertificateArn(
                      this,'my-cert', myCertArn),
        endpointType: apigw.EndpointType.REGIONAL,
    },
    deployOptions: {
        stageName: 'qa'
    },
});
    const hostedZone = route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'hosted-zone-lookup', {
        domainName: `mydomain.com`,
    });
    new route53.ARecord(this, 'api-gateway-route53', {
        recordName: `test-api.mydomain.com`,
        zone: hostedZone,
        target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new route53Targets.ApiGateway(restApi)),
    });
```

Comment: Does doing above also create a default url? AFIAK, you could create a RestAPI and register a new domainName thats maps to the default url.

Comment: we need a custom domain, to register Api Gateway in DNS provider(ex: Route53) we first create a customDomain on Api Gateway like above, then add DNS entry to pointing to this custom domain.

Comment: can this all be done in a CDK application? Or there is manual step involved. looks like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-certificatemanager-readme.html just creates a DNS record from CDK app.

Comment: I updated answer with cdk code import acm and to add route53 entry

Comment: Thanks. it's failing to create certificate and i can't figure out why. but I will ask in a separate question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why you deploy API Gateway, the url of the endpoint will have [AWS provided](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/data-protection-encryption.html#data-protection-in-transit) SSL certificate.

> The APIs created with Amazon API Gateway expose **HTTPS endpoints only**. API Gateway doesn't support unencrypted (HTTP) endpoints.

You have no control over its policies, and there is **no AWS API** to get its details. But, you can check it in the browser after connecting to the API endpoint, e.g. in Firefox:

[image]

If you want to control your own certificates, you need your [own domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-custom-domain-tls-version.html).